# status not uploading using socialauth android on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

i am not getting any error , i give corrent key and secrent . i get connect to facebook but status is not update on facebook.
here is my code

OnCreate Method

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);
    share.setText("Share");
    share.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    share.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_gradient);
    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
    adapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facebook);
    adapter.enable(share);
```

}

ResponseListener Class

```
      private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener 
    {

          @Override

          public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
         {

    final String providerName = values.getString(SocialAuthAdapter.PROVIDER);  

    update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
                        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxt);
                    update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                            adapter.updateStatus(edit.getText().toString(), new MessageListener(), false);
                        }
                    });
```

}

Comment: Did you check the logcat?

Comment: yes i check....Facebook error: (#200) The user hasn’t authorized the application to perform this action...i have added permission in my app like email" ,"publish_stream","publish_actions","status_update....